# How can I easily setup scheduled recurring tasks on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How can I easily set up scheduled recurring tasks on Google Cloud Platform to trigger Google Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously you could setup up Cron jobs using Google App Engine which tigger a PubSub triggered Google Cloud Function, however, this defeated the 'serverless' approach as you are introducing infrastructure to manage and it can take a moderate amount of work to setup the Cron jobs.

You can now use the newly released [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) which is completely managed, cheap and which makes it very easy to create scheduled jobs via Google PubSub and via HTTP requests. These in turn can trigger the Google Cloud Functions at regular intervals per unit of time or at a specific time of the day/week/month down to a one-minute interval. *Note that you are still required to have an App Engine instance in one of the supported regions.*